# Cypress AWS SDK Getting error > global is not defined

Tags: cypress, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am trying to integrate AWS SDK secret manager with my cypress test cases. I started getting error when trying to import secret manager.

The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> global is not defined

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

### We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.

Secrete Manager code:

```
`import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

;('use strict')

class SecretsManager {
static async getSecret(secretName: string, region: string) {
const config = {
region: region,
}
const secretsManager = new AWS.SecretsManager(config)
try {
const secretValue = await secretsManager
.getSecretValue({
SecretId: secretName,
})
.promise()
if ('SecretString' in secretValue) {
return secretValue.SecretString
}
const buff = new Buffer(secretValue.SecretBinary as string, 'base64')
return buff.toString('ascii')
} catch (err: any) {
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console
console.log(err)
if (err.code === 'DecryptionFailureException') throw err
else if (err.code === 'InternalServiceErrorException') throw err
else if (err.code === 'InvalidParameterException') throw err
else if (err.code === 'InvalidRequestException') throw err
else if (err.code === 'ResourceNotFoundException') throw err
}

    return null

}
}
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-default-export
export default SecretsManager
```

Getting error even on importing the above file in my test script.

Trying calling aws secret manager from my cypress scripts. any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

AWS SDK awaits a global objet from you. Try to use **mock-aws-s3** adding a mock object to **S3.getObject** in beforeEach hook and restores the original S3 method in afterEach hook.

```
describe('test', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    AWSMock.mock('S3', 'getObject', (params, callback) => {
      callback(null, { Body: 'Mocked Body' });
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    AWSMock.restore('S3');
  });

  it('getObject method, () => {
    cy.wrap(AWS.S3.getObject()).should('deep.equal', { Body: 'Mocked Body' });
  });
});
```